# controller's before_save methods aren't called in testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, post, controller, minitest

Following is `rails-api` only app.

In users_controller.rb

```
  def sign_up
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      user = {}
      user[:name] = @user.name
      user[:email] = @user.email
      user[:access_token] = @user.auth_token
      user[:message] = "Successfully Signed up"
      render json: user, status: 200
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private 
  def user_params
    params.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

In model/user.rb

```
attr_accessor :password
before_save :encrypt_password, :generate_token
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX } , uniqueness: { case_sensitive:false }
validates :password, :confirmation => true, presence: true, :length => {:within => 6..20}
validates_presence_of :password_salt, :password_hash
validates_presence_of :auth_token
```

In test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb

```
test "should create user" do
  assert_difference('User.count') do
    post :sign_up, {email: 'user_3@example.com', name: 'user_3', password: 12345678, password_confirmation: 12345678}
  end
end
```

user model attributes are:

```
name email password_hash password_salt auth_token
```

The test above is failing b'cos @user.errors shows

```
<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fd826117140 @base=#<User id: nil, name: "user_3", email: "user_3@example.com", password_hash: nil, password_salt: nil, auth_token: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:password_salt=>["can't be blank"], :password_hash=>["can't be blank"], :auth_token=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

On `@user.save` `before_save :encrypt_password, :generate_token` aren't called.

Using `gem 'bcrypt'` to store the password as hash.

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `before_save :encrypt_password, :generate_token` use `before_validation :encrypt_password, :generate_token`. Code in `encrypt_password` and `generate_token` is not triggered because you validate model data first and since data is not valid there is no need to trigger `before_save` because record would not be saved anyway

Comment: Thank you. This worked. While in development it didn't cause any error. But in testing it did. I am kinda partially understanding this. Could you please help me here.

Comment: Maybe in development you test it on existing user?

Comment: No, it's signup action. So a new user.

Comment: That's weird for me that in development you are able to create new user record from sign up action however is hard to say why this happen by just looking at the snippets you provide. I'm afraid I can't help you to detect reason of this

Comment: I will try looking into it. But thanks a lot. I did get to know `before_save` vs `before_validation`